# gzip compression not working in joomla 2.5

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5, google-pagespeed

I'm totally sick with my site.

When I check compression with [this site](http://checkgzipcompression.com), this says me You're blessed! It's GZIP Enabled.  78.6% Was saved by compressing this page with GZIP.

But when I check with [google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) it says me to fix enable compression in the css and js files.

I have this code for compression in .htaccess file:

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

And obviously, I have enabled compression from backend in joomla 2.5

Is google page speed test says something else than gzip compression?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Google is asking you to compress external CSS and JavaScript (which you can't do). Check those files that Google is complaining about and I'm almost positive that you will notice that they do not belong to your website.

Comment: css and javascripts are minified. but still says to compress. what does this mean? and those files belong to my website (not external resources).